# Angular 2 Webpack 2 - Sass not working in component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack, webpack-2

I have been following the guide here https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components in terms of incorporating scss files as my styles for angular 2 components, but it's not working.

How do I incorporate scss files into my angular 2 components with webpack?

Here is the main component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'src/app/app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {}

    name: string = 'My Demo';
}
```

**I know the article recommends using raw-loader in my webpack config but that's not working either**

The scss just remains in the  without being preprocessed.

You can see the particulars for my basic project at the plnkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/eG1POBcBL8kGpvrhh3yW?p=info

Follow the README instructions to build and serve.

Doesn't seem like there's much up to date documentation on including scss files in components?

Comment: If it is not working is *not* a question. What is the actual question?

Comment: @RomanC how do I get component working with sass? How do I incorporate scss files into my angular 2 components with webpack?

Comment: @RomanC I updated the questions :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new project with SCSS working out of the box, generate it with [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and you're good to go. Much easier then implementing sass by yourself imo.

```
ng new sassy-project --style=sass
```

or:

```
ng new sassy-project --style=scss
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! Seems like overkill so such a standard requirement though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do thin in next way:

Command line inside project folder where your existing package.json is:

```
npm install node-sass sass-loader raw-loader --save-dev
```

In webpack.common.js, search for "loaders:" and add this object to the end of the loaders array (don't forget to add a comma to the end of the previous object):

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
}
```

Then in your component:

```
@Component({
  styleUrls: ['./filename.scss'],
})
```

If you want global CSS support then on the top level component (likely app.component.ts) remove encapsulation and include the SCSS:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  styleUrls: ['./bootstrap.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: ``
})
class App {}
```

Comment: My project is generated using angular-cli and I am not able to find webpack.common.js file on root of my project. The only place I can find webpack.common.js is inside node_modules of webpack dev and it is not safe to edit there.

Comment: Yea this solution is similar to `https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components` but it doesn't work. Did you end up figuring it out? having the same issue.